# What are the alternatives to SwissStop Blue v-brake pads

Tags: brakes, rims, tandems

We've got a tandem with [Rigida Andara CSS tungsten carbide rims](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/rigida-andra-30-26-%28559%29-mtb-css-rim-black-32-hole-rohloff-drilling-prod13269/) and Swisstop Blue v-brake pads. We're happy with the performance and life of both of these over the last 1000 miles.

The problem is that *only* Swisstop Blue blocks are recommended. I've been led to believe that other blocks will wear out too quickly on tungsten carbide rims, possibly leaving a rubbery deposit on the rims.

I'd like to know of more than one manufacturer or supplier (preferably in the UK) who can provide suitable replacement v-brake block cartridges, so that I have options if the Swisstop ones are unavailable or become expensive. I don't like being tied to a single brand for what should hopefully be quite long-lived rims.

Are there any reasonable alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kool stop R9 Magura HS33](http://www.koolstop.eu/index.php?id=63&L=1) Pads are made to work with Rigida CSS rims.

Also  [V-Brake inserts](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/koolstop-koolstop-v-brake-block-inserts-for-rigida-carbide-rims-prod19778/)  by kool stop for Rigida CSS rims.